# C# TreeView and binding to a database

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm querying a database via a stored procedure and getting data back. which I'm populating into an object as such:

```
private GetMiscVars _batchVariablesData;
        public GetMiscVars BatchVariablesData
        {
            get { return _batchVariablesData; }
            set
            {
                if (_batchVariablesData == value) return;
                _batchVariablesData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BatchVariablesData");
            }
        }
```

In my XAML I have this:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Batch Data" ItemsSource="{Binding BatchVariablesData}">
            <TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VarDesc}" />
                </DataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

What I am seeing when my code runs is my parent node is blank instead of saying "Batch Data" like I hoped and my child nodes return the name of the ObservableCollection used in calling the database, in this DgTabData.
So, where am I screwing things up?
Thanks

To clarify a little bit more, I have a stored procedure that returns data that looks like this:

```
VarId   EventId VarDesc
11      2489    WP1.WC01 Quantity
1196    2489    WP1.WC01 Brew Number
1197    2489    WP1.WC01 Operator Name
1216    2489    WP1.WC01 Integer Test
1217    2489    WP1.WC01 Logical Test
1218    2489    WP1.WC01 Float-4 Test
1219    2489    WP1.WC01 Float-3 Test
```

I want to take the VarDesc field and place it in a TreeView under a heading of Batch Data. Once I can figure this out I want to be able to grab the VarId and EventId values from the item selected in the TreeView as I will use those to populate a datagrid.

Comment: How `GetMiscVars` is declared?

Comment: It is a class for accessing the database. I get the data by BatchVariablesData.GetData(myParameters), which is taking place and returning data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a `TreeView` displays hierarchical data. That means that your data must have a `public` collection property to use for the child nodes. Next, to display hierarchical data, you need to declare a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), rather than trying to define the controls as you were. Try this XAML instead:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfParents}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix.YourClassName}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfChildrenPropertyInParent}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyInParent}" /><!-- Parent DataTemplate -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> <!-- Child DataTemplate -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyInChild}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

As I said, *a TreeView displays hierarchical data. That means that your data must have a public collection property to use for the child nodes*. So create a class, let's say named `Data`, with a property to hold the `Batch Data` text, let's say named `Name`, and an `ObservableCollection<string>` property, let's say named `Items` to hold the `VarDesc` column values.

Then you need to populate the collection with the items returned from the stored procedure in any way you see fit. Finally, create an `ObservableCollection<Data>` property, let's say named `DataItems` in the code behind or view model and add your `Data` class, complete with collection items. Then you could bind to the `TreeView` like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix.Data}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> <!-- Parent DataTemplate -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> <!-- Child DataTemplate -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: So I can't take an ItemsSource that is populated by a stored procedure that I'm using for a data grid and also use it for for a TreeView (which is what I'm basically trying to do)? I just want to take one field from this ItemsSource and display it in a TreeView with a fixed label. Well then once they select an item in the TreeView I'm going to populate another grid but first things first...

Comment: Your best bet is to create classes with the properties required for display and or editing and populate `ObservableCollection<T>` with them for displaying in the UI.

Comment: When I try this everything under the TreeView.Resources tosses an error saying "Resource is never used"

Comment: You *have* replaced `YourXamlNamespacePrefix` for your *actual* XAML Namespace Prefix, haven't you?

Comment: Yeah, but had the wrong name. This is darn close. I have the parent node of Batch Data now and it shows the VarDesc underneath it, BUT each VarDesc has its own Batch Data node. So instead of one Batch Data with 7 VarDesc under it I have 7 Batch data each with its own VarDesc. I'm thinking the issue is in what you referred to as DataItems, I'm looking into that more right now.

Comment: Dude, it's simple... the parent nodes come from the items in the parent collection... you want ONE item in that collection. The child items come from the child collection *inside* the parent class... that is the one that you need to fill with the returned data.

Comment: Dude, binding a database to a grid is simple, to a combobox is simple, to a listbox is simple. Once I figured out that TreeView doesn't like working the same way ( yeah for consistency) then it was simple. It did mean I couldn't use the existing class for accessing the database due to the way it was setup so after creating a new class and setting things up as you described it was easy to get working. Not as easy as binding to a datagrid but doable. Thanks for your help.